# Linear independence of $\cos(n\theta)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I was trying to see if the cosines of the (certain) integer multiples of a certain angle were linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$.

In particular I was looking at when $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{p(p+1)}$ and when the numbers are $\cos((kp+k-p)\theta)$ where $k = 0,\ldots, p-1$ for prime $p$.

I was looking at small cases, like when $p = 5$, but even then I wasn't able to come up with an efficient method to test whether or not they are linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: You may want to look at the Chebyshev polynomials: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Comment: yeah, i looked at them and realized that for certain primes, for example, primes of the form 4k-1, I could find my required cosines to be roots of the chebyshev polynomials. I know the chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal to each other, but does that mean directly that the root of one chebyshev polynomial is linearly independent over the rationals from the roots of other chebyshev polynomials?